# How can mainstream OO languages support strong binary operations by classes?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, polymorphisms

Section 24.2  in *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce compares ADT and existential objects,in terms of how well they support strong binary operations:

> Other binary operations cannot be implemented without concrete, privileged access to the representations of both abstract values. For example,
>   suppose we are implementing an abstraction representing sets of numbers. After scouring several algorithms textbooks, we choose a concrete representation of sets as labeled trees obeying some particular complex
>   invariant. **An eﬃcient implementation of the union operation on two sets
>   will need to view both of them concretely,** as trees. However, we do **not
>   want to expose this concrete representation anywhere in the public interface** to our set abstraction. So we will need to arrange for union to have
>   privileged access to both of its arguments that is not available to ordinary client code—i.e., **the union operation must live inside the abstraction
>   boundary**. We call such operations **strong binary operations**.

and says strong binary operations can't be expressed as methods of existential objects:

> Strong binary operations, on the other hand, cannot be expressed as
>   methods of objects in our model. We can express their types just as we
>   did for weak binary methods above:
>
> ```
> NatSet = {∃X, {state:X, methods: {empty:X, singleton:Nat→X,
> member:X→Nat→Bool,
> union:X→NatSet→X}}}
> ```
>
> . But there is **no satisfactory way to implement an object of this
>   type**: **all we know about the second argument of the union operation** is
>   that it provides the operations of NatSet, but these do not give us
>   any way to ﬁnd out what its elements are so that we can compute the
>   union.

but then says that mainstream OO languages provide support for strong binary operations by classes (instances of which are supposedly existential objects):

> **The
>   classes in mainstream object-oriented languages like C++ and Java are designed to allow some forms of strong binary methods**, and are actually best
>   described as a kind of compromise between the pure objects and pure ADTs
>   that we have seen in this chapter. In these languages, the type of an object
>   is exactly the name of the class from which it was instantiated, and this type
>   is considered distinct from the names of other classes, even if they provide
>   exactly the same operations (cf. §19.3). That is, a given object type in these
>   languages has a single implementation given by the corresponding class declaration. Moreover, subclasses in these languages can add instance variables
>   only to those inherited from superclasses. These constraints mean that every
>   object belonging to type C is guaranteed to have all the instance variables
>   deﬁned by the (unique) declaration of class C (and possibly some more). **It
>   now makes sense for a method of such an object to take another C as an argument and concretely access its instance variables, as long as it uses only
>   instance variables deﬁned by C**. This permits strong binary operations such as
>   set union to be deﬁned as methods.

When a method in a class has an argument which is another object of the same class, how can the method "concretely access the instance variables" of the other object?

Does the book assume that the class makes the instance variables only privately accessible, and doesn't provide public accessible methods to access the instance variables? (I guess yes, because it seems to me that the third quote has the same situation as   the second quote where it be impossible for `union` method on existential objects.)

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have experience with C++/Java?

Comment: Methods can access private instance variables.

Comment: Yes. What I don't understand is how an instance method of an object can access private instance fields of another object of the same class.

Comment: It just can. The rules of the language allow it.

Comment: Perhaps you should study a mainstream OO language such as C++ or Java.

Comment: Yes, I think I am relatively informed about C++ or Java on this matter, but I can't figure it out. Does the book assume that the class makes the instance variables only privately accessible, and doesn't provide public accessible methods to access the instance variables?

Comment: Instance variables are supposed to be hidden and accessible only via public methods. This is known as *data hiding*, and is why we have silly getters and setters. This is not something that the book *assumes*, it is the idea behind object oriented programming.

Comment: Do you mean the third quote assumes the class provides public methods to access private instance variables? If it does, where does it mention the assumption explicitly? (In the second quote, there is no such assumption)

Comment: "we do **not want to expose this concrete representation anywhere in the public interface**"

Comment: Is it correct that the sentence doesn't say we provide a public method to access the private variables?

Comment: You shouldn’t be reading this text that closely. It’s not scripture.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus *this is known as data hiding*—not quite. If i can still get the data through a getter, you havent hidden it at all. Getters and setters control access to data, but private fields hide it.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have never read a scripture. TAPL is the best that I have found, so I have no choice but to read part of it closely. I am open to other books, if you can recommend, though I am still wondering about the questions here.

Comment: Monographs like TAPL are not written like poetry or like legal texts. They are trying to convey a general message, but don't pay attention to each and every word in each and every sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will attempt an answer, though, the discussion in comments with @yuval-filmus seems to be going in the right way.

Let's recap: The book discusses ADTs against objects in their strictest sense.

ADTs are entirely public about their unique representation. Belonging in the ADT means satisfying said representation, and so binary methods can rightfully assume that both operands have that exact representation.

Objects are entirely opaque about their non-unique representation. Belonging in the object type means satisfying its interface, with no guarantees as to how this is achieved internally, and so binary methods may only assume that the two objects can respond to the same set of messages, but are quite possibly implemented entirely differently.

Even if the interface has a getter `getFoo`, that is no guarantee that the object has a `foo` field that you could poke at directly. Maybe some mock object is faking it with a method that returns a constant `Foo`. All you know as a client is that it supports a `getFoo` call.

---

Where the class-based object approach differs from the pure object approach is that the knowledge of the type of an object (the class it belongs to) gives you some guarantees about the structure of the object, and so, allows you to partially break the abstraction barrier.  Because all objects of a class must have been built with, at least, a call to the constructor of that class, you can guarantee the presence of some fields (initialized during that constructor), and so the language lets you access those directly, foregoing the mandatory message-passing of the pure object style.

This is a strength and a weakness:

- because you have access to the concrete representation, you might be able to implement operations more efficiently,
- but because you ask for a member of the class, a "mock" implementation is no longer a valid object for this operation: if you want to allow such an object, you must define an interface, and you are effectively back to a pure-object approach.

---

As in my other answer to one of your question, this paper is extremely relevant:

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf
"On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited", by William R. Cook

Of particular interest are section 3.3 on autognosis, which hints at why binary methods in the ADT style are strong, whereas in the object style are weak, and section 5 which explains a bit the difference between what is considered a pure object approach and the more general objects available in Java. (You can program in the pure object style in Java, but you have to follow a given discipline about not breaking certain abstraction boundaries, which relates to the discussion you've had in the comments)

---

I hope this makes sense, I'm sorry you had trouble with my other answer, this is a hard topic to get your head around, but once you have fixed your misunderstandings you will see it is not that complex!

Comment: Thanks. I am slowly understanding your replies. Meanwhile, thanks again if you could also consider https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/113618/does-an-adt-have-multiple-or-only-one-representations-implementations

Comment: Thanks. "Because all objects of a class must have been built with, at least, a call to the constructor of that class, you can guarantee the presence of some fields (initialized during that constructor), and so the language lets you access those directly, foregoing the mandatory message-passing of the pure object style."  In such case, when a strong operator takes another object in the same class as an argument, and wants to access the private fields of the object, does the operator not need a public method?  Could you give some example in Java?

Comment: http://paste.awesom.eu/eloz&ln In this code, a method of some class `Doggo` receives as argument another object of the same class `Doggo`, and is allowed to access the private field `booped`. This is against the pure object approach ideology, where one should instead use the getter/setter methods. But it is considered "fair", because the object is from the very same class, so the type system allows you to see the actual implementation, possibly allowing you to do more than just through the public interface.