# Why are ADT packages opened immediately after they are built, while existential objects opened as late as possible?

Tags: programming-languages, type-theory, polymorphisms

Section 24.2  in *Types and Programming Languages* by Pierce defines ADTs in existential types:

> **A conventional abstract data type (or ADT)** consists of (1) a type name A, (2) a concrete representation type T, (3) implementations of
>   some operations for creating, querying, and manipulating values of
>   type T, and (4) an abstraction boundary enclosing the representation
>   and operations. Inside this boundary, elements of the type are viewed
>   concretely (with type T). Outside, they are viewed abstractly, with
>   type A. Values of type A may be passed around, stored in data
>   structures, etc., but not directly examined or changed—the only
>   operations allowed on A are those provided by the ADT. ... We ﬁrst
>   create an existential package containing the internals of the ADT:
>
> ```
> counterADT =
> {*Nat,
> {new = 1,
> get = λi:Nat. i,
> inc = λi:Nat. succ(i)}}
> as {∃Counter,
> {new: Counter,
> get: Counter→Nat,
> inc: Counter→Counter}};
>
> > counterADT : {∃Counter,
> {new:Counter,get:Counter→Nat,inc:Counter→Counter}}
> ```
>
> We can open it for example
>
> ```
> let {Counter,counter} = counterADT in
> counter.get (counter.inc counter.new);
> > 2 : Nat
> ```

and then defines existential objects  in existential types:

> **A counter object** comprises two basic components: a number (its internal state), and a pair of methods, get and inc, that can be used
>   to manipulate the state. We also need to ensure that the only way that
>   the state can be queried or updated is by using one of these two
>   methods. This can be accomplished by wrapping the state and methods in
>   an existential package, abstracting the type of the state. For
>   example, a counter object holding the value 5 might be written
>
> ```
> c = {*Nat,
> {state = 5,
> methods = {get = λx:Nat. x,
> inc = λx:Nat. succ(x)}}}
> as Counter;
> ```
>
> where:
>
> ```
> Counter = {∃X, {state:X, methods: {get:X→Nat, inc:X→X}}};
> ```
>
> We opens it for example:
>
> ```
> let {X,body} = c in body.methods.get(body.state);
> > 5 : Nat
> ```

and  compare ADTs and existential objects:

> **when programming with ADTs**, packages are opened immediately after they are built; on the other hand, **when packages are used to model
>   objects** they are kept closed as long as possible—until the moment
>   when they must be opened so that one of the methods can be applied to
>   the internal state.

- What does "*when programming with ADTs, packages are opened immediately after they are built; on the other hand, when packages are used to model objects they are kept closed as long as possible*" mean?

  They are both opened in the binding parts of the `let` terms, which can be anywhere (not immediately) after they are built. So their timings seem to be the same to me.
- What are the differences in the definitions of ADT and of existential objects in terms of existential types, which lead to the timing difference of their opening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see an instance of the claimed property in the two definitions of `add3`.

---

In the ADT style, `add3` is defined as:

```
let { Counter, counter } = counterADT in
let add3 = λ (c : Counter). counter.inc (counter.inc (counter.inc c)) in
counter.get (add3 counter.new);
```

As you see, in order to call about `inc`, one must already have opened the existential package. You cannot write the `inc3` function in the "ambient scope", as `Counter` is not an ambient type, but a type encapsulated in the `counterADT` package.

You could repackage everything after the first call to `inc`, and re-open the package before the next call, but that would be somewhat pointless.

---

In the object style, `add3` is defined as:

```
add3 = λ (c : Counter). sendinc (sendinc (sendinc c)))
```

Here, the client code does not open the existential package themselves.  Instead, each call to `sendinc` will open the package when it needs to run `inc`, and will repackage the output.  The client could just do the same, but that is not the intent of this style (they would be breaking the abstraction).

---

So, the confusion might be that you understood the sentence as "the packages are open at a given time", as opposed to "a programmer would be expected to open the package at a given time".

---

The difference in timing comes from the way we want to use these two mechanisms.

The ADT mechanism is one where we have a single representation, that we wish to hide, while giving some actions to perform on that representation.  Because there is a single representation, it is perfectly acceptable to unpackage it once and for all.

The object mechanism is one where we want to potentially allow multiple representations that all share some actions to perform on them.  Because we want to allow multiple representations, each package should be responsible for knowing how to perform the abstract action on its concrete representation.  If we were to unpackage the existential type early, we would locally be restricted to a given representation.

This becomes very interesting when thinking about binary operations over the packaged type: in the ADT style, the two operands are guaranteed to share the same representation, whereas in the object style, each operand could have its own concrete representation and its own way of implementing the binary operation.

http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~wcook/Drafts/2009/essay.pdf

^ This paper, "On Understanding Data Abstraction, Revisited", by William R. Cook gives a lengthy explanation of the difference in power between these two approaches, and is, in my opinion, an excellent read.

Comment: Thanks. Could you also consider https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/113428/how-can-mainstream-oo-languages-support-strong-binary-operations-by-classes?

Comment: I am struggling to understand your reply. There seems to be something that I am assumed to know but I don't.

Comment: Thanks. Is prototype approach in javascript the object mechanism?

Comment: Somewhat? Prototypes are used as an alternative to classes, in order to have some notion of inheritance across objects. Prototypes have a somewhat more dynamic nature (objects get their prototype altered while the program is running), whereas classes should be defined statically in your code. Modern JavaScript has retrofitted a class system on top of the prototype system: it eventually gets compiled down to prototype hacking (at far as I know...), so the two definitely have some overlap in their intent and implementation.

Comment: In the  two counter examples quoted in my post, what is the ADT in the first example and what is the type of the existential objects in the second example? Which does the following quote (in the next comment) says that the ADT is: the type variable `Counter` bound by `let`, or is the actual type component in `counterADT` that is bound to `Counter` by `let`? Does the quote  in the next comment says the type of the existential object is type name `Counter`, which is bound to `{∃X, {state:X, methods: {get:X→Nat,inc:X→X}}}`?

Comment: on p374 " in the ADT style, the type `Counter` is a bound type variable introduced by the let construct, while in the object style Counter stands for the whole existential type `{∃X, {state:X, methods: {get:X→Nat,inc:X→X}}}`.
Thus, at run time, all the counter values generated from the counter ADT are
just bare elements of the same internal representation type, and there is a sin-
gle implementation of the counter operations that works on this internal rep-
resentation. By contrast, each counter object carries its own representation"

Comment: Re. your ADT question, I think I would answer "neither": usually what is meant by ADT is "a type and collection of operations over that type". So following this, `{∃ Counter, { new : ... } }` would be the ADT, while you could call the thing named `Counter` the underlying type, or the concrete representation of the abstract type.

Comment: Re. your object question, assuming I understood it correctly, I would answer "yes". The type named `Counter` is the existential object type, indeed bound to the type you quoted.

Comment: So are  both ADT and existential object type the same  existential types, because it doesn't make difference that the existential type for the existential object  bundles the functions into a subrecord denoted by field `method`? What are the differences between ADT and existential object type then?

Comment: So, while the two existential types are isomorphic, what distinguishes the style is the way in which we use them. In the ADT approach, the `new` field should always be set to `1`. A counter is a value of type `Nat`, where the type system only lets us use it as an argument to `get` or `inc`. In the object approach, the "corresponding" field, `state`, is not always set to `1`. In fact, it it not always even a `Nat`! For instance, I could write an object with state `(Nat, Bool)`, s.t. the `Bool` is set to `false` if the counter was never incremented, and `true` when `inc` is called.

Comment: Thanks.  (1) In our previous comments (and the book), the type of the existential object is `{∃X, {state:X, methods: {get:X→Nat,inc:X→X}}}`. (2) According to the paper by Cook linked by you, the type of objects, also called an interface of objects, for this example is purely based on the signatures of the methods: either `interface Counter = {get: Counter->Nat, inc: Counter-> Counter}` according to Figure 7, or `Counter` defined by `Counter = F (Counter)` where `type F(t) = {get: t->Nat, inc: t->t}` according to Section 3.9 on p9. Are (1) and (2) consistent? Is (1) implementation of (2)?

Comment: Indeed, (1) is pretty much an implementation of (2). Maybe not quite entirely, because whereas in (2), the `inc` method returns a proper `Counter`, in (1), `inc` returns an internal state, so to get back a proper counter, you need to do the whole repackaging as seen in `sendinc`.